# Is there a way to prevent Eclipse/Netbeans from being able to format compilable code?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

I'm writing a program that decreases (butchers) code readability without affecting the compile-ability of said code. However, if one could simply open eclipse and ctrl+alt+f the code back to its former pristine self, the program wouldnt be very use(less)full. I know that if a necessary curvy brace is absent, eclipse wont format, but is there some other way to hinder formatting without making the code uncompileable?

Comment: Replace all variable/class/method names with randomly-chosen names.

Comment: I've already done that, and some other stuff like make boolean comparisons unnecessarily complicated( if(true) becomes if (!(true && false ||..) , but I  also compact the code, which is why i need to remove formatting

Comment: aren't there myriad code obfuscators that do this already ?

Comment: As long as there is an AST, it's possible to format code. May I ask what your trying to build here?

Comment: @krystan -- do they prevent ctrl+alt+f ?

Comment: @compsciballa: Formatting "obfuscation" is trivially reversible, so I wouldn't bother.

Comment: I guess the problem is to make it nigh unreversible.

Comment: no, but nothing stops that, how are you going to stop it ? if its parsable code the parsing algorithms are gonna reformat it to something sensible.

Answer (score 3):

No. There is no way to prevent this. Even if you found a way to prevent Eclipse and/or Netbeans from formatting your source, who's to stop someone from building their own formatter? Or simply from using a completely different IDE? A smart code formatter may not even need the code to be compileable. It could make assumptions about the correct placement of braces and format the code according to its guess until the code is corrected.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that a user will always be able to do "ctrl+alt+f" in Netbeans and retrieve the standard indention formatting.

If you want to make it unreadable, you're going to have to generate random names for all variables and functions.  There's not much else you can do.

I have never tried to solve the problem from your direction, but I have spent some time opening up unreadable code in the past.  And the hardest thing I have ever encountered was when there was a lot of complicated logic all in one statement (on one line).